# Required type:UnifiedNativeAd but Provided:NativeAd in play-services-ads:20.1.0

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

Earlier code was like this, but upgrading to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.1.0' it says UnifiedNativeAd deprecated.

```
AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this.requireActivity(), "ad unit")
            .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) 

                    template.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
                 }
            })
             .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    failed = 0;
                 }
             })
            .build();
```

Then I changed to this as given https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates

```
AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(this.requireActivity(), "ad unit")
            .forNativeAd(new NativeAd.OnNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNativeAdLoaded(NativeAd NativeAd) 

                    template.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    template.setNativeAd(NativeAd);
                 }
            })
             .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                    failed = 0;
                 }
             })
            .build();
```

But now it shows error in **template.setNativeAd(NativeAd);**
It is saying **Required type:UnifiedNativeAd but Provided:NativeAd**
Can anyone help me in this

Comment: check your template view and also clear project then rebuild, if not then invalidate cache and restart from file menu,

Comment: I tried it, cleaning also don't work and here is template view <com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
                android:id="@+id/my_template".                        
               android:visibility="gone"
              app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_medium_template_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />       It was working fine before updating to ads:20.1.0